# Making my own Singly Linked List, cannot make insert_after function

Tags: python, function, singly-linked-list

I'm making my own Singly Linked List in python. I learned that when I have to insert after 'p' node, first, making a new node that pointing next of p, and then pointing new node with next of p.

But when I run the code below, I got error

```
class SList:
    class _Node:
        def __init__(self, element, next = None):
            self._element = element
            self._next = next

        def element(self):
            return self._element

        def next(self):
            return self._next

        def set_element(self, element):
            self._element = element

        def set_next(self, next):
            self._next = next

    def __init__(self, head = None):
        self._head = head
.
.
.
.
```

```
def insert_after(self, element, p): 
        # element is new node, and p is the node already in SLL.
        new_node = self._Node(element, p.next())
        p.next() = new_node
```

Output becomes like this...

```
File "<ipython-input-100-f46148f593d4>", line 74
    element.next() = new_node
    ^
SyntaxError: can't assign to function call
```

So I can't continue, because when I entered value like this...

```
temp = SList()
temp.insert_first("A")
temp.insert_first("B")
temp.insert_first("C")
temp.insert_first("E")
temp.insert_first("F")

temp.insert_after("D", "C")
# I want A,B,C,D,E,F in continuously
```

The outcome is...

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-101-e9d4a6a04b21> in <module>()
      6 temp.insert_first("F")
      7 
----> 8 temp.insert_after("D", "C")
      9 
     10 # s1.delete_first()

<ipython-input-96-aa629a206e57> in insert_after(self, element, p)
     71 
     72     def insert_after(self, element, p):
---> 73         new_node = self._Node(element, p.next)
     74         p.next = new_node
     75 #         new_node = self._Node(element, p._next())

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'next'
```

What's wrong with insert_after function???

Answer (score 1):

You can't assign to a function call, so you probably meant to write

```
p._next = new_node
```

Then you pass string 'C' when you are supposed to pass the node from the list, as you stated in the comments. You should probably find the node with `self._element == 'C'` and pass it to the method instead.
So add new method to SList

```py
def find(self, value):
    current = self._head
    while current:
        if current._element == value:
            return current
        current = current._next
    return None
```

and then call

```
temp.insert_after("D", temp.find("C"))
```

Comment: It doesn't work either...actually It doesn't print "can't assign to function call" anymore, but the output is "'str' object has no attribute 'next'"...still have an error...

Comment: I am not familiar with phyton but I see the following. Your insert function has the signature **insert_after(self, element, p)**, and  you call it with **insert_after("D", "C")**, whereby element and p are strings, but p should be of type _Node and not String.